# UIButtons are not correctly shaped on all devices

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uibutton, autolayout

I've an UIView Controller with four square buttons and I've set them round with a border. It works perfectly on iPhone 8 and iPhone X but in iPhone SE and iPhone 8 Plus the UIButtons are not round anymore. I've set the UIButtons to be square and to keep that ratio with Auto-Layout but it doesn't appear to work.

In my **ViewController.Swift**, I've linked the four UIButtons and then I've applied the same code as below :

```
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftButtonImage: UIButton!


// Edit it to round
topLeftButtonImage.layer.cornerRadius = topLeftButtonImage.frame.size.width/2
topLeftButtonImage.clipsToBounds = true

// Add border
topLeftButtonImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // Button border color
topLeftButtonImage.layer.borderWidth = 4 // Button border width
```

Here you can see the behaviour on iPhone SE and iPhone 8 Plus. **iPhone 8 and iPhone X are fine**.

[image: Screenshots iPhone Simulator]

**Auto-Layout constraints :**

[image: Auto-Layout in action]

Comment: In what `func` is this code executed?

Comment: @Flexicoder in the `func viewDidLoad()`

Comment: try to move the code to func viewDidAppear()

Comment: @JulienW. as the posted answer below, your view has not been added to the view hierarchy at that point, so won't know the correct width of the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set button cornerRadius in viewDidLayoutSubviews method of viewcontroller

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    // Edit it to round
    topLeftButtonImage.layer.cornerRadius = topLeftButtonImage.bounds.size.height / 2
    topLeftButtonImage.clipsToBounds = true

    // Add border
    topLeftButtonImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // Button border color
    topLeftButtonImage.layer.borderWidth = 4 // Button border width
}
```

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is called every time the controller's view is updated, rotated, or changed.

Comment: or scrolled also.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's really `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` that needs to be overridden for this, not `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` as it says in the code snippet. The answer should be edited to reflect that.